# How to jump for the present intent to another intent after a given period of time?

Tags: android, andengine

I am using an andengine .My idea is to display a intro screen and the after 2 seconds jumps to the main activity. As of yet I can display the intro screen , I want it to wait for 2 to 3 seconds and then jump to another intent . here is my code ,thank you for your time .

```
package com.example.lines;

import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;


public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {


    private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
    private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800;

    private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion;
    @Override

    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, 
            new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        try {

            ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("intro.png");
                }
            });
            backgroundTexture.load();
             this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);

        return scene;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your question you simply need to show a "loading panel" at the begin of your activity.

If this is your case I suggest you to use an asyncTask at the begin of your activity to display a popup that will stay on the screen for x seconds.

Try something as follow:

```
 public class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //method that will display your loading popup 
        showLoadingPanel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //method that will hide your loading popup
        hideLoadingPanel();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Runnable... params) {
        try {
               Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps;)

Answer (score 0):

1) The first scene you show to the user should be the splash scene

2) Register a Timer to show the menu/game scene after a time has passed

Example:

```
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
            {
                mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                // load menu resources, create menu scene
                // set menu scene
                // disposeSplashScene();
            }
    }));
```

Code from [matim-dev blog.](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-5.html)

Comment: @user3721487 no problem. Now please accept the answer (click on the check mark) to mark the question as answered :)